# Solving a boundary value problem using scipy solve_bvp (How to determine boundary value to use)

Tags: python, numerical-methods

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72NVp.png)

I am trying to solve the boundary value problem shown in the image attached. My issue is I am not sure what boundary condition to use in the scipy(solve_bvp) code as I am provided with theta(0) = theta0 and dtheta/ds (L) = 0. I have split the Second-order equation into two first-order differential equations.

```
def F(s, t, fg, fx, phi):   #First-order differential equations
    F = np.zeros(2)
    F[0] = t[1]     #dt0 = t1
    F[1] = s * fg * np.cos(t[0]) + s * fx 
* np.cos(phi) * np.sin(t[0])
    return F
```

This is how I've defined the boundary conditions at the moment but I don't think its correct.

```
def bc(t, dt, theta0):
    fa = theta0      # t(0) = theta0
    fb = 0      #t'(L) = 0
```

For all the examples I have seen online on BVP, the boundary conditions supplied are both of the same order: either y(a) = A and y(b) = B or y'(a) = A and y'(b) = B.

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You need to solve both DE at once, thus the state vector has dimension 4. One has to be careful with parameters in the functions for solve_bvp, as they are also used for constants that get fitted during integration. Use global variables, or define them as class methods where the parameters are also class fields. There is no restriction on what the boundary conditions are, only that 4 slots have to be filled.

Comment: @LutzLehmann so you are saying that I need to solve the theta DE with the phi DE at the same time? How am I meant to combine the two? Or can I put two DE in the solve_bvp function?

Comment: Yes, the equations are coupled, so they need to be solved simultaneously. Make the state vector to contain `u=[phi, dphi, theta, dtheta]` and produce from it the derivatives vector `du=[dphi, d2phi, dtheta, d2theta]`. Then the boundary condition reads as `bc(u0,uL): return u0[0]-phi0, u0[2]-theta0, uL[1], uL[3]`.